# How do I extract the Oauth2 access token in a Spring application using code grant flow?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I have followed [this guide.](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/)

I have a simple Oauth2 webapp using code grant authorization flow. I have a @GetMapping endpoint (as per the tutorial) that returns user information retrieved from a service provider I'm using. Since this correctly returns my information to the webapp, I can tell the code grant flow has worked. Code for working endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public Map<String, Object> user(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User principal) {
    return principal.getAttributes();
}
```

Now I want to create a new @GetMapping where I use the access token to query the API of the service provider that just authorized us.

The problem is that the example above somehow magically makes the request for me based solely on configuration and only returns user info. Now I want to get the access token for this session that Spring stores somewhere to access the API however I like "manually".

How can I extract the access token in my new @GetMapping?

I have been searching a lot, but I am new to both Oauth2 and Spring, and there is so much spring classes and tutorials that I "can't see the forest because of all the trees".

I appriciate any help.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

Add the following:

```
@Autowired
private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService;

private String getSessionBearerToken() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient client =
            authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
                    oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
                    oauthToken.getName());
    return client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
}
```

This method will get you the access token when you call it.